# How do I stop row selection when a button in DataGridTemplateColumn is clicked in wpf DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid in wpf with a Template column containing three buttons. When any of these buttons are clicked, the row containing those buttons is also highlighted. I want to disable this row highlighting and selection. Only highlighting is not required, the row shouldn't be selected.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserResize="False" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Width="80" Header="L-Op">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="LogicalPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Button Content="{Binding LogicalOperator, Converter={StaticResource LogicalOperatorValueConverter}}" Foreground="#548DD4" FontStyle="Italic"
                                    Click="LogicalOperator_Click" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,0,0,3" Width="30">
                                <Button.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                        <ContentPresenter />
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Button.Template>
                            </Button>
                            <Button x:Name="btnAdd" Height="20" Width="20" Style="{StaticResource ShowHideButton}" Margin="2,0" Click="btnAdd_Click" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                                <Image Source="Add.png" />
                            </Button>
                            <Button x:Name="btnRemove" Height="20" Width="20" Style="{StaticResource ShowHideButton}" Click="btnRemove_Click" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Image Source="remove.jpg" />
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Had you tried with PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown?

Comment: no, I'm a bit of new comer w.r.t to WPF... therefore, didn't try PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown. I had a vague idea of setting Handled to true and bubbling of events but it didn't work in MouseLeftButtonDown event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of use Click Event you can use `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown`and set `e.Handled = true;` in the handler. You can do your code in this handler and your row shouldn't get highlighted or selected.

**There is one big difference however: usually a Click event occur when the mouse button is up, in this way it will be raised immediately.**

Comment: I've handled both PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown as well as PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp event and all the operations that were performed in Click event are now done in PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp. Besides in PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown I'm saving the button that initiated the event and if same button initiates the PreviewMouseButtonUp event than event is handled otherwise it simply returns

Thanks a lot for the help